# Difference between scikit-learn and caret GBM results?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, scikit-learn, r-caret

I'm getting drastically different F1 scores with the same input data with scikit-learn and caret. Here's how I'm running a GBM model for each.

scikit-learn (F1 is default output)

```
est = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators = 4000, learning_rate = 0.1, max_depth = 5, max_features = 'log2', random_state = 0)
cv = StratifiedKFold(y = labels, n_folds = 10, shuffle = True, random_state = 0)
scores = cross_val_score(est, data, labels, scoring = 'f1', cv, n_jobs = -1)
```

caret (F1 must be defined and called):

```
f1 <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
      f1_val <- F1_Score(y_pred = data$pred, y_true = data$obs, positive = lev[1])
      c("F1" = f1_val)
 }
set.seed(0)
gbm <- train(label ~ ., 
           data = data, 
           method = "gbm",
           trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 3, 
                                    summaryFunction = f1, classProbs = TRUE),
           metric = "F1",
           verbose = FALSE)
```

From the above code, I get an F1 score of ~0.8 using scikit-learn and ~0.25 using caret. A small difference might be attributed to algorithm differences, but I must be doing something wrong with the caret modeling to get the massive difference I'm seeing here. I'd prefer not to post my data set, so hopefully the issue can be diagnosed from the code. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a random state parameter you specify in caret?

Comment: @blacksite, not specific to caret, but I set the seed prior to initializing the model.

Answer (score 1):

GBT is an ensemble of decision trees. The difference comes from:

- The number of decision trees in the ensemble (`n_estimators = 4000` vs. `n.trees = 100`).
- The shape (breadth, depth) of individual decision trees (`max_depth = 5` vs. `interaction.depth = 1`).

Currently, you're comparing the F1 score of a 100 **MB** `GradientBoostingClassifier` object with a 100 **kB** `gbm` object - one GBT model contains literally thousands of times more information than the other.

You may wish to export both models to the standardized PMML representation using [sklearn2pmml](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) and [r2pmml](https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml) packages, and look inside the resulting PMML files (plain text, so can be opened in any text editor) to better grasp their internal structure.

Comment: In other words, to make your GBT objects roughly the same size, please re-train your `GradientBoostingClassifier` with parameters `n_estimators = 100` and `max_depth = 1`.

Comment: Also, the function `prSummary` will compute the F score for you.